# I have a filter problem in VB.net and using access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, filter, datagridview

I want to filter datagridview with multiple column, first filter using one column and then filter again in filtered data using 2nd column. We have to use 2 textboxes. e.g:

I want to display `Barq` with `galaxy` Car:

[image: Bar1]

Comment: What is the type of the `DGV.DataSource`? It'll be more helpful if you show at least how do you populate the DGV.

Comment: @Jimi, the request was for filtering rather than sorting. As such, you would use Filter, RowFilter and Where.

Comment: Repost: If the GDV's DataSource is a BindingSource binding a DataTable, use the `BindingSource.Filter` property. If the DataSource is a DataTable, use the `DataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter` property (e.g., `[Source].Filter = "Column1 = 'Something' AND Column2 LIKE '%omethingels%'"`), if it's an IList, List, BindingList, use LINQ's Select()/Where()/Etc() methods to filter the list

Comment: i am using DataBinding

Comment: Thanks @Jimi its working

Answer (score 0):

here i have used "Like" in filter, u can use "like" or "=".

```
 Dim dv As DataView = DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView
        dv.RowFilter = "OfficeName like '%Barq%' and BrokerNamelike '%galaxy Car%'"
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
```